# Shiny tableOutput for list elements from multiple .txt files

Tags: r, shiny

I have multiple text files that I imported into shiny as a list.

```
#ui
library(shiny)

fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose File",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".dp_txt", ".is_txt")),
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      
      tableOutput("files"),
    )
  )
)

#server

function(input, output, session){
  
  output$files <- renderTable({
    
    req(input$file1)
    
    library(readr)
    
    files <- lapply(input$file1$datapath, function(x) read_csv(x))
    files
  })
}
```

I want to be able to select the different elements of this list and display them as tables. How can I individually output each table within my list in shiny (i.e., let the user select which table they want to display)? Every element (table) within the list will have a name. Can I use somehow use `selectInput()` to call each table within the list according to that tables name? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the expected outcome? Would you like to merge those tables or let the user choose which table is displayed?

Comment: @ ismirsehregal
Sorry! Let the user choose which table is displayed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following:

The file input is observed for changes and updates the choices of the `selectizeInput`.

Once the files are uploaded the choices are populated and a table is displayed according to the selection.

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

# create dummy CSVs -------------------------------------------------------
DF1 <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = letters[1:3])
DF2 <- data.frame(x = 4:6, y = letters[4:6])
DF3 <- data.frame(x = 7:9, y = letters[7:9])
DF4 <- data.frame(x = 10:12, y = letters[10:12])

mapply(
  write.csv,
  x = list(DF1, DF2, DF3, DF4),
  file = list("DF1.csv", "DF2.csv", "DF3.csv", "DF4.csv"),
  row.names = FALSE
)

# shiny app ---------------------------------------------------------------
ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput(
      "files",
      "Choose File",
      multiple = TRUE,
      accept = c(
        "text/csv",
        "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
        ".dp_txt",
        ".is_txt"
      )
    ),
    selectizeInput(
      inputId = "selected_table",
      label = "Table Selection",
      choices = NULL,
      selected = NULL,
      multiple = FALSE
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(DTOutput("table"))
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$files, {
    freezeReactiveValue(input, "selected_table")
    updateSelectizeInput(session,
                         inputId = "selected_table",
                         choices = input$files$name,
                         server = TRUE)
  })
  
  table_list <- reactive({
    req(input$files)
    setNames(lapply(input$files$datapath, function(x) {
      fread(x)
    }),
    input$files$name)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDT({
    req(table_list(), input$selected_table)
    table_list()[[input$selected_table]]
  }, server = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

PS: feel free to replace `DTOutput` with `tableOutput` if preferred.

Comment: @ZT_Geo this could be done inside the `reactive` function. However, I'd suggest to ask a follow-up question, as this is out of the scope of your original question. Cheers

Comment: This is great! Thank you! I am going to have to perform several manipulations of the list data before displaying the data.frames. How can I manipulate the list data from your example before displaying the data. 

For example, If I wanted to change the name of the first column of every data frame within the list to "First" how would I do that? If I knew the list was defined as "files" I would insert files <- lapply(files, setNames, "First"). I guess I am just not fully understanding if the list is defined as and how to alter the tables within the list from here.

Comment: Thanks! I have posted the question in the comment at the following link.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73723078/manipulate-list-data-within-shiny-reactive-function