# Manipulate list data within shiny reactive function

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny application which reads in multiple csv/txt files, combines them into a list and reactively outputs the data table of the selected file. See below.

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(data.table)


ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput(
      "files",
      "Choose File",
      multiple = TRUE,
      accept = c(
        "text/csv",
        "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
        ".dp_txt",
        ".is_txt"
      )
    ),
    selectizeInput(
      inputId = "selected_table",
      label = "Table Selection",
      choices = NULL,
      selected = NULL,
      multiple = FALSE
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(DTOutput("table"))
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$files, {
    freezeReactiveValue(input, "selected_table")
    updateSelectizeInput(session,
                         inputId = "selected_table",
                         choices = input$files$name,
                         server = TRUE)
  })
  
  table_list <- reactive({
    req(input$files)
    setNames(lapply(input$files$datapath, function(x) {
      fread(x)
    }),
    input$files$name)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDT({
    req(table_list(), input$selected_table)
    table_list()[[input$selected_table]]
  }, server = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, I want to take the raw data-frames within the list through ~20 transformations (the same transformations for each data frame) prior to outputting the selected data table. I would like to do this for all of the data tables not just one I am outputting as I plan to make a summary tab. I will also need to do things like make new lists from the original list during this data processing.

As a basic example lets say I want to start by removing the first two rows from every data-frame within my list prior to outputting the selected table using something like  `lapply(list_of_df, function(x) as.data.frame(x[-c(1,2),]))`. How would I go about doing this with the shiny app example given above?

Comment: if you don't need the unprocessed data frames, why not do this when you read them in with `fread()`? Or else, if you need the originals for other reasons, just do the processing before outputting the table, doing this just on the currently selected data frame (so no need to add a new lapply either way)

Comment: @giocomai . Thanks for the comment. 

I am new to reactive functions in shiny and got some help putting this shiny app together in a previous question. I am not clear on what is assigned as the list in the script. In previous (non-reactive) shiny apps I have been able to give the list a name and make transformations that way, but I am not clear on if the list is assigned a name in this example above. Would you be able to share a code example of what I should add and where? I appreciate it!

Comment: @giocomai. Also, I am eventually planning on making a summary tab for all of the different tables so I think it would be best if I take every table through all of these manipulations.

Comment: What I was suggesting, is that you do this processing when you import them, so where you have `fread(x)` you just go with `fread(x)[-c(1,2),]`, or assign `df <-fread(x)`, and do all sorts of processing on that df, within that `lapply` call you have there

Comment: @giocomai. Thanks for your response. I get what you are saying now. I will have over 20 processing steps so it will probably get to messy to try to squeeze them all into that import lapply().

As for your second suggestion,  I am planning on creating other lists from this original list  to use during processing and at the end of my processing make a summary tab with with a table of all containing statistics from all of the data frames. 

That's why I was hoping to figure out a way to name the list and continue to update it, while still maintaining this reactive selection. Other thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simply add another `reactive` which is based on the `table_list`.

Here the first column is dropped:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

# create dummy CSVs -------------------------------------------------------
DF1 <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = letters[1:3])
DF2 <- data.frame(x = 4:6, y = letters[4:6])
DF3 <- data.frame(x = 7:9, y = letters[7:9])
DF4 <- data.frame(x = 10:12, y = letters[10:12])

mapply(
  write.csv,
  x = list(DF1, DF2, DF3, DF4),
  file = list("DF1.csv", "DF2.csv", "DF3.csv", "DF4.csv"),
  row.names = FALSE
)

# shiny app ---------------------------------------------------------------
ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput(
      "files",
      "Choose File",
      multiple = TRUE,
      accept = c(
        "text/csv",
        "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
        ".dp_txt",
        ".is_txt"
      )
    ),
    selectizeInput(
      inputId = "selected_table",
      label = "Table Selection",
      choices = NULL,
      selected = NULL,
      multiple = FALSE
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(DTOutput("table"),
            DTOutput("filtered_table"))
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$files, {
    freezeReactiveValue(input, "selected_table")
    updateSelectizeInput(session,
                         inputId = "selected_table",
                         choices = input$files$name,
                         server = TRUE)
  })
  
  table_list <- reactive({
    req(input$files)
    setNames(lapply(input$files$datapath, function(x) {
      fread(x)
    }),
    input$files$name)
  })
  
  filtered_table_list <- reactive({
    req(table_list())
    lapply(table_list(), function(DT) {
      DT[, -c(1)]
    })
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDT({
    req(table_list(), input$selected_table)
    table_list()[[input$selected_table]]
  }, server = FALSE)
  
  output$filtered_table <- renderDT({
    req(filtered_table_list(), input$selected_table)
    filtered_table_list()[[input$selected_table]]
  }, server = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

PS: If not yet done, check out library([data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table)) for fast and
memory efficient data manipulation:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html

https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/blog_assets/datatable_Cheat_Sheet_R.pdf

Comment: Thank you again! I will check out the data.table library as well, thanks for the tip!