# R-Shiny - how to make "dependencies" in output reactive

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, reactive

I am exploring the shiny world and came across a very simple question. How can I make "reactive" the dependencies of a `selectInput` element?
See code for example:

```
db1 <- readRDS("folder/file1.rds")    
app <- shinyApp(
      server = function(input, output, session) {
        
          text1 <- db1$var1[1]
          text2 <- db1$var2[2]              
          
        observeEvent(input$selectfile, {
          db1 <- readRDS(file.path("folder",input$selectfile))
          text1 <- db1$var1[1]
          text2 <- db1$var2[2]
          }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
        
        output$text1 <- renderText(text1)
        output$text2 <- renderText(text2)
      },
      
      ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(,
       dashboardPage(
         options = list(sidebarExpandOnHover = TRUE),
         header = dashboardHeader(title="Dashboard"),
         sidebar = dashboardSidebar(minified = TRUE, collapsed = TRUE),
         body = dashboardBody(
           textOutput("text1")
           textOutput("text2")
           ...
           ),
         controlbar = dashboardControlbar(selectInput(inputId='selectfile','Select File',choice = list.files('folder/'),selected=list.files('folder/'))),
         title = "DashboardPage"
       )))
    )
    
    app
```

The app is pretty simple (is a toy example, obviously a proper app would be pretty much complex): at the start, it imports `db1` from a folder in which I have `file.rds` and `file2.rds`; then write some variables from this dataset into `text1` and `text2` and then render this texts into `output$text1` and `output$text2`.

The problem is: when I update the file through the UI (see the `selectInput` field), for example with `file2.rds`, the `output$text1` and `output$text2` doesn't update (indeed, they are not reactive).
I have tried:

```
server = function(input, output, session) {

          text1 <- db1$var1[1]
          text2 <- db1$var2[2]              

        observeEvent(input$selectfile, {
          db1 <- readRDS(file.path("folder",input$selectfile))
          text1 <- db1$var1[1]
          text2 <- db1$var2[2]
        output$text1 <- renderText(text1)
        output$text2 <- renderText(text2)
          }, ignoreInit = TRUE)

        output$text1 <- renderText(text1)
        output$text2 <- renderText(text2)
      },
```

But this doesn't work as well.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You should avoid wrapping `renderText` in `observeEvent`. Use `reactive`, `eventReactive`, `reactiveVal` or `reactiveValues` to pass data to `renderText`, which than will change due to its reactive dependencies.

Comment: @ismirsehregal thanks for the hint, however doing 

`eventReactive(input$selectfile, {
          db1 <- readRDS(file.path("folder",input$selectfile))
          text1 <- db1$var1[1]
          text2 <- db1$var2[2]
        output$text1 <- renderText(text1)
        output$text2 <- renderText(text2)
          }, ignoreInit = TRUE)` 

does not seem to work as well

Comment: Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73713283/9841389) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73726867/9841389) for *reproducible* examples. PS: You should also avoid wrapping `renderText` in `eventReactive`. Usually all `renderXXX` functions should be used on the first level of the server function.