# Follow up (Delete rows from data frames in shiny using DataTable (server side))

Tags: r, shiny

This question is a follow up from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74436109/delete-rows-from-data-frames-in-shiny-using-datatable-server-side%22). However, in this case I am wondering how to do the exact same row deletion if the list you are deleting from is in the form of a reactive expression. I keep getting back the error

#Warning: Error in table_list: unused argument (tmp_table_list).

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

# create dummy CSVs -------------------------------------------------------
DF1 <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 2:4)
DF2 <- data.frame(x = 4:2, y = 5:7)
DF3 <- data.frame(x = 7:9, y = 8:10)
DF4 <- data.frame(x = 10:8, y = 11:13)

mapply(
  write.csv,
  x = list(DF1, DF2, DF3, DF4),
  file = list("DF1.csv", "DF2.csv", "DF3.csv", "DF4.csv"),
  row.names = FALSE
)

# shiny app ---------------------------------------------------------------
ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput(
      "files",
      "Choose File",
      multiple = TRUE,
      accept = c(
        "text/csv",
        "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
        ".dp_txt",
        ".is_txt"
      )
    ),
    selectizeInput(
      inputId = "selected_table",
      label = "Table Selection",
      choices = NULL,
      selected = NULL,
      multiple = FALSE
    ),
  ),
  mainPanel(DTOutput("table"),
            actionButton("deleterow", "Delete row(s)"),
            plotOutput("plot"))
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$files, {
    freezeReactiveValue(input, "selected_table")
    updateSelectizeInput(session,
                         inputId = "selected_table",
                         choices = input$files$name,
                         server = TRUE)
  })
  
  table_list <- reactive({
    req(input$files)
    
    setNames(lapply(input$files$datapath, function(DT) {
      fread(DT)
    }),
    input$files$name)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$deleterow, {
    if(!is.null(input$table_rows_selected)){
      tmp_table_list <- table_list()
      tmp_table_list[[input$selected_table]] <- table_list()[[input$selected_table]][-input$table_rows_selected]
      table_list(tmp_table_list)
    }
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDT({
    req(table_list(), input$selected_table)
    table_list()[[input$selected_table]]
  }, server = FALSE)
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    temp <- table_list()[[input$selected_table]]
    req(NROW(temp) > 0)
    plot(temp$x, temp$y)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can I make this reactive expression work as a reactiveVal()?

Comment: As mentioned in my previous answer you cannot modify a reactive expression in multiple places. A `reactive` is defined once and it's return value will change only if its dependencies change - it doesn't accept input parameters - that's why you get the error. You'll need to stick with `reactiveVal` or `reactiveValues`. If you have upstream reactives which the `reactiveVal` should be based upon, just use `observe` to change the `reactiveVal` whenever the upstream `reactive`s change.

Comment: @ismirsehregal Thanks for this explanation. I do have several upstream reactives the `reactiveVal` depends upon. How do you implement using `observe` to change the `reactiveVal` whenever the upstream `reactive` values change? Would this be separate `observe` calls for each `reactive` or could you do this all at once? Also the `reactiveVal` which was originally a `reactive` has many downstream `reactives` which depend upon it. Is it proper to take a `reactiveVal`  to make new `reactive` expressions that depend upon it?

Comment: A single `obeserve` should be sufficient to update the `reactiveVal`. Creating downstream `reactive`s based on it is reasonable. I'll try to come up with an example tomorrow - currently I'm only on mobile. Cheers

Comment: As this doesn't answer the above question I posted an example [here](https://gist.github.com/ismirsehregal/1ca6c17879e5bb91610d3fd31a7ffe24).